# Escape character = SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a row in my column like

```
update my_table 
SET column_name = 'vector = 1 AND value IN('A','B','C')'
```

I think the problem is that I don't know how I escape the = sign

Just to be clear; `vector = 1 AND value IN('A','B')` is the existing value in my row I want to update to `vector = 1 AND value IN('A','B','C')`

Tips on how I can do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not run in problem with the = sign but the quote sign.

```
'vector = 1 AND value IN(''A'',''B'',''C'')'
```